# Manipulando a opacidade de um objeto(control)

Tags: c#, windows-phone

**Exemplo:** Ao apertar de um botão vou exibir um `painel` editando apenas sua visibilidade, dá certo, mais fica sem nenhum efeito, fica uma transição seca.

Daí tive a ideia de ao apertar o botão exibir o painel com opacidade 0 e depois ir incrementando ela aos poucos. Mas como o processador do smartphone é rápido nem dá pra ver o efeito, então pensei em implantar um `sleep`, o resultado foi que ao apertar no botão demora uns 2 segundos para exibir o painel, mas exibe ele seco, sem transição, o sleep só fez demorar a ação do botão.

**Código:**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ // Ao apertar o botão
    if (painel.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
    { //olha se o painel já está visivel
        int cont = 200;
        while (cont > 0)
        { // vai decrementando, e diminuindo sua opacidade
            painel.Opacity = cont * 0.5;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2); //tentativa de retardar um pouco
            if (cont == 1) // quando a opacidade for 1 eu irei ocultar o painel
                painel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            cont -= 1;
        }
    }  
    else
    { // se ao apertao do botão ele estiver oculto
        int cont = 0;
        painel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible; //torna ele visível
        painel.Opacity = 0; // deixa com opacidade 0
        while (cont < 100)
        { //vai aumentando a opacidade ate ela ser 99 
            painel.Opacity = cont * 0.5;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2); / tentatida de retardar
            cont += 1;
        }
    }     
}
```

Como já disse, com o `sleep`, quando eu pressiono o botão ele espera uns 2 segundos e exibe o painel sem ir controlando a opacidade, só exibe ele, sem 'transição'. Estou implantando isso em um app, onde o `painel` é um `StackPanel`. É um app para Windows Phone 8.1 com Silverlight.

Comment: Já pensou em usar [Animations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189019%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Não sabia desse método, fu pelo raciocínio da linguagem em si, sem métodos, mas valeu, vou testar agora, posto resultados!

Comment: Deu certo! Pelo menos para controlar a opacidade em crescente, ou seja para mostrar o painel, para ocultar ele com animação ainda não está funcionando direito, pois tenho de tonar ele Visible ou Collapsed

Comment: Consegui, vou postar a resposta completa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom, então com a ajuda de @ramaral ficou assim:

**.xaml da página, parte do painel**

```
<!-- Uma 'div'. -->
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">

    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <!-- Animação para ocultar o painel -->
        <Storyboard x:Name="ocultar">
            <!-- Uma animação Double, pois opacidade pe float, determino aqui onde vou aplicar,
             quando começa, quando termina e gero um método para quando ele é completada. -->
            <DoubleAnimation Completed="DoubleAnimation_Completed"
                Storyboard.TargetName="painel"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                From="1.0" To="0.0"  Duration="0:0:1" />
        </Storyboard>

        <!-- Animação para mostrar o painel -->
        <Storyboard x:Name="mostrar">
        <!-- Mesma coida do anterior, mas aqui estou aumentando a opacidade, e não tenho método
        de complete, pois torno o painel visível antes de executar a animação -->
            <DoubleAnimation x:Name="aMostrar" 
            Storyboard.TargetName="painel"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1" />
        </Storyboard>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <!-- Painel -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Height="700" Name="painel" Background="Crimson"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="400"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**.cs**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ // Ao pressionar do botão
    if (painel.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
    { //se o painel estiver visivel ele chama a animação p/ ocultar
        ocultar.Begin();
    }  
    else
    { //se o painel estiver oculto, ele torna visivel e chama a animação de mostrar
        painel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        mostrar.Begin();
    }     
}

private void DoubleAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ //metodo chamado quando a anicação de ocultar termina, ele apenas deixa o painel oculto
    painel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```